# Using Form and Input elements correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to make reusable Form and Input components and so far got to following:

**Form**

```
import React from 'react'
import classNames from 'classnames/bind'
import styles from './style.scss'

const cx = classNames.bind(styles)

export default class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this)
  }

  submitForm (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.onSubmit()
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <form className={cx('Form')} onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
        {this.props.children}
      </form>
    )
  }
}

Form.propTypes = {
  children: React.PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  onSubmit: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

**Input**

```
import React from 'react'
import classNames from 'classnames/bind'
import styles from './style.scss'

const cx = classNames.bind(styles)

export default class Input extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      value: this.props.value || ''
    }
    this.changeValue = this.changeValue.bind(this)
  }

  changeValue (e) {
    this.setState({value: e.target.value})
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className={cx('Input')}>
        <input
          type={this.props.type}
          value={this.state.value}
          required={this.props.required}
          onChange={this.changeValue}
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder || ''}
          noValidate />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Input.propTypes = {
  type: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  value: React.PropTypes.string,
  required: React.PropTypes.bool,
  placeholder: React.PropTypes.string
}
```

I then use them within some another component, lets say `HomePageComponent`

```
<Form onSubmit={this.loginUser}>
  <Input type='email' placeholder='email' />
  <Input type='password' placeholder='password' />
  <Input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</Form>
```

This all works well, but how would I get input values and use them to set state of `HomePageComponent` to `this.state= { email: [value from input email], password: [value from password input] }`

Comment: you want set state of parent , when form's inputs "Chaged" ? . or you just want values when submit event

Comment: @Utro I guess keeping track of forms state is a more valuable option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store the value in the `Input` component.

You can get the input values by keeping [references](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) to individual inputs:

```
<Form onSubmit={this.loginUser}>
  <Input ref='email' type='email' placeholder='email' />
  <Input ref='password' type='password' placeholder='password' />
  <Input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</Form>
```

Then, in `loginUser` you can access these using:

```
const email = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.email).value;
const password = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.password).value;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you add the name attribute to your input elements, you can access their values this way. Hope this helps

```js
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const form = e.target.elements;
    console.log(form.email.value);
    console.log(form.password.value);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <form className={cx('Form')} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <Input type='email' placeholder='email' name='email' />
        <Input type='password' placeholder='password' name='password' />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```